# Installing Kinect SDK v2 failed

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, kinect, kinect-sdk

Hey I would love if someone could help me with my problem, I got a new Notebook with Windows 8.1 installed, first installing the Kinect SDK v2 was no problem, just download, install, use... But the Notebook was broken after 2 month and I got it repaired, they changed the mainboard and now the system runs clean.

But when I try to install the Kinect SDK v2 again the setup fails. In detail it says:

*An error occured. Please check the setup logs for more information.*

So did I, but I can't see whats happening or how to fix it, hopefully anyone here can help:

---

```
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:16]i001: Burn v3.7.1224.0, Windows v6.2 (Build 9200: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe, cmdline: ''
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20150910222919.log'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Kinect for Windows SDK v2.0_1409'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:20]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:21]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i100: Detect begin, 5 packages
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i000: Setting string variable 'VCRTx64Installed' to value '1'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i000: Setting string variable 'VCRTx86Installed' to value '1'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i052: Condition 'VCRTx86Installed' evaluates to true.
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i052: Condition 'VCRTx64Installed' evaluates to true.
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i101: Detected package: VCRTx86, state: Present, cached: None
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i101: Detected package: VCRTx64, state: Present, cached: None
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i101: Detected package: x64Runtime, state: Absent, cached: None
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i101: Detected package: x64SDK, state: Absent, cached: None
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i101: Detected package: x64Drivers, state: Absent, cached: None
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:22]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i200: Plan begin, 5 packages, action: Install
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VCRTx86
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VCRTx64
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_x64Runtime' to value 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20150910222919_0_x64Runtime_rollback.log'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_x64Runtime' to value 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20150910222919_0_x64Runtime.log'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_x64SDK' to value 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20150910222919_1_x64SDK_rollback.log'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_x64SDK' to value 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20150910222919_1_x64SDK.log'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_x64Drivers' to value 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20150910222919_2_x64Drivers_rollback.log'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_x64Drivers' to value 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\Kinect_for_Windows_SDK_v2.0_1409_20150910222919_2_x64Drivers.log'
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i201: Planned package: VCRTx86, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i201: Planned package: VCRTx64, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i201: Planned package: x64Runtime, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i201: Planned package: x64SDK, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:27]i201: Planned package: x64Drivers, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:35]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:29:35]i300: Apply begin
[0C2C:1410][2015-09-10T22:30:14]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0C2C:1410][2015-09-10T22:30:19]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0C2C:1410][2015-09-10T22:30:23]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\{2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}\.be\KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}\KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe'
[0C2C:1410][2015-09-10T22:30:23]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}, version: 2.0.1410.19000
[09FC:1664][2015-09-10T22:30:38]e000: Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract all files from container.
[09FC:106C][2015-09-10T22:30:38]e000: Error 0x80004005: Faild to begin and wait for operation.
[09FC:106C][2015-09-10T22:30:38]e000: Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract payload: a1 from container: WixAttachedContainer
[09FC:106C][2015-09-10T22:30:38]e312: Failed to extract payloads from container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe, error: 0x80004005.
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:30:38]e000: Error 0x80004005: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[0C2C:1410][2015-09-10T22:30:38]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}
[0C2C:1410][2015-09-10T22:30:38]i352: Removing cached bundle: {2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2f7f3dc4-de9a-4605-821f-b686f26392d8}\
[09FC:0B90][2015-09-10T22:30:39]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80004005, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Thanks for spending yout time on my problem.

Greetings...

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure how I got it working now, but i posted the same question in microsoft community board and got the tip to run sfc /scannow . Even it didn't recognize any failures I got a fresh copy of the Kinect Installer from another source and it worked after trying about 25 times.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows 10. What finally worked for me was to delete the program cache folder (`'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache'`).

Note that `C:/ProgramData` is a hidden folder.

I tried `sfc /scannow` and it did not work for me.